# Why is my delegate found nil even if my picker view as always data in?

Tags: swift

On this PreferencesVC, I have two pickerViews for a user to select two currencies to be sent to the main user interface. While saving the changes and sending the data, it says that it is unexpectedly found nil. How come as my pickerViews always have data from a non-empty tuple?

```
protocol ChangeCurrencyDelegate {
    func userEnteredNewCurrency(top: CurrencyTuple, bottom: CurrencyTuple) 
}

class ExchangePreferencesVC: UIViewController {

  @IBOutlet weak var topCurrencyLabel: UILabel!
  @IBOutlet weak var topCurrencyPicker: UIPickerView!
  @IBOutlet weak var bottomCurrencyLabel: UILabel!
  @IBOutlet weak var bottomCurrencyPicker: UIPickerView!

  var delegate: ChangeCurrencyDelegate?

  var topPickerOptions = [(name: String, symbol: String, flag: UIImage)]()
  var bottomPickerOptions = [(name: String, symbol: String, flag: UIImage)]()

  var userCurrencyChoice: Currencies!

  override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    topPickerOptions = currencyISOCode
    bottomPickerOptions = currencyISOCode
  }

   // User top and bottom pickerView choices
  func createTopAndBottomCurrency() {
    let topUserIndex = topCurrencyPicker.selectedRow(inComponent: 0)
    let bottomUserIndex = bottomCurrencyPicker.selectedRow(inComponent: 0)
    let topUserChoice = currencyISOCode[topUserIndex]
    let bottomUserChoice = currencyISOCode[bottomUserIndex]
    userCurrencyChoice = Currencies(top: topUserChoice, bottom: bottomUserChoice)
  }

  // MARK: - Cancel and Save Changes actions
  @IBAction func saveChanges(_ sender: Any) {
    delegate?.userEnteredNewCurrency(top: userCurrencyChoice.top, bottom: userCurrencyChoice.bottom)
    self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
  }
}
```

delegate is assigned this way ->

```
// MARK: - Delegate of the ChangeCurrency protocol
extension ExchangeRateViewController: ChangeCurrencyDelegate {
  func userEnteredNewCurrency(top: CurrencyTuple, bottom: CurrencyTuple) {
    self.topFlag.setImage(top.flag, for: .normal)
    self.topSymbol.text = top.symbol
    self.bottomFlag.setImage(bottom.flag, for: .normal)
    self.bottomSymbol.text = bottom.symbol
  }

  override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if segue.identifier == "goToPreferences" {
      let destinationVC = segue.destination as! ExchangePreferencesVC
      destinationVC.delegate = self
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: share how you assign the `delegate` ?

Comment: Is this what you were asking?

Comment: Where is `createTopAndBottomCurrency` called? In `saveChanges` you use `userCurrencyChoice` which is an implicitly unwrapped optional, and it's initialized in  `createTopAndBottomCurrency`, so if that function is never called, calling `saveChanges` will result in runtime error.

Comment: Unrelated: You should always declare `delegate` as *weak* therefore `ChangeCurrencyDelegate` as `: class`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's your `prepare` method...

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if segue.identifier == "goToPreferences" {
      let destinationVC = segue.destination as! ExchangePreferencesVC
      destinationVC.delegate = self
    }
}
```

Consider what happens if the segue's identifier doesn't exactly match `goToPreferences`. The segue will still happen, but the delegate won't be set. So check your segue identifier, and also add some code to handle the case where you don't recognize the identifier. At the very least, you should log a message so that you can more easily spot the problem.